# Counting characters and running an if statement

Tags: c#

I appreciate the time you spend reading this :)

Basically im trying to run an if command if a string is greater than so many characters.

So im running a bunch of line.conatins to filter out what I dont want, but I also want to add a character count, so if the line has less than 30 characters it will filter it out.

So basically, im looking for something like this in C# visual studio 2008

```
if (line.contains > 30 characters) 
{
    Run code...
}
```

Im not to sure of the right syntax to use, and google hasnt been very forthcoming.

I appreciate any help. Thanks, Jason

Wow thanks for the fast response guys, but with lots of trial and error i came up with this

```
int num_count = line.Length;
                    if (num_count > 30) { }
```

seems to work

Comment: Googling "length of a string C#" comes up with about 4 million results.  What were you searching under?

Comment: Im not an epic coder like u guys, Im an aircon engineer :p I do this as a hobby and still learning, self taught. I read countless threads, in the end i got it from typing line. and reading all the different options then figuring maybe variables will work in c# like they do in php as I couldnt think of much else :)

Comment: All working now tho guys, thank you for your amazingly fast responses

Comment: @user2905326 My tone may have seemed harsh, but I was more curious about what you were actually searching under if Google wasn't turning up anything.  I do know that everyone has to start somewhere.  Check out http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-C-ebook/dp/B00ERG0H7E/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1382543071&sr=8-1&keywords=head+first+C%23, which is a great place to get started with C#, and very readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string data = "fff"

if (data.Length > 30)
{
 // MAgic stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
            string str = "yourstring";
            int i = str.Length;
```

Also try to post code next time you ask something it helps a lot when determining exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The short, but näive, answer is to use this property:

[String.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx)

You might want to think about what you mean by character. .NET's String class is a counted sequence of UTF-16 code units, which it types as `Char`. There are either one or two UTF-16 code units in a Unicode code point, and it's easy to calculate as you step through each `Char`. Where two code units are used, they are called the low and high surrogates.

But also note that Unicode can represent diacritics and such as separate code points. You might want to exclude them in your count.

Putting them together:

```
using System.Linq;
...
var test = "na\u0308ive"; // want to count ä as one character
var categoriesNotToCount = new []
{ 
    UnicodeCategory.EnclosingMark,
    UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark, 
    UnicodeCategory.SpacingCombiningMark 
};
var length = test
    .Count(c => 
        !categoriesNotToCount.Contains(Char.GetUnicodeCategory(c)) // we just happen to know that all the code points in categoriesNotToCount are representable by one UTF-16 code unit
        & !Char.IsHighSurrogate(c) // don't count the high surrogate because we're already counting the low surrogate 
    );
```

It all comes down to what you're after. If it's the number of UTF-16 code units you want then, for sure, `String.Length` is your answer.